# How to design the vertical scroll bar or customize the vertical scroll bar design?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Can you Please help me out, how to design the vertical scroll bar using CSS... Is there any way to customize the vertical scroll bar design using css or css3... Thanks in Advance..

Comment: It's hard to design a Scrollbar. So i use JScrollPane. http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: can you share your code to explain where you want to customized your scroll bar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://giangnguyendesign.com/) website. It uses a customized scrollbar for the `-webkit-` based browsers. When you inspect the css file, it's pretty clear what css is used.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) and (min-device-width: 1025px) {
html {  overflow: hidden; }
body {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 12px;
    top: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    background-color: #fff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: #eee;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

However, http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ is the best example of cross-browser scrollbar customizer that i've crossed so far...

Comment: No, the code I posted only works on `webkit` based browsers being Chrome and Safari. If you want to use customized scrollbars in Firefox, which is based on `gecko`, I would recommend using http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
.scrollbar{ position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 85px; width: 499px;  
overflow-y: scroll;  
overflow-x: hidden;  
padding-right: 5px;  
visibility: visible;  
border: thin solid white;  
background-color: #336699;  
scrollbar-face-color: #336699; scrollbar-3dlight-color: #336699; scrollbar-base-color:      #336699;  
scrollbar-track-color: #336699; scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #000; scrollbar-arrow-color: #000;  
scrollbar-shadow-color: #fff; scrollbar-highlight-color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.scroll
{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 212px;
    height: 320px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```